# Is there any way to work with index of an option?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-select

I want to add remove 'option1' and append another option in the same position using jQuery:
suppose my options are:

```html
<select id="selectBox" name="selectBox">
  <option value="option"> option1 </option>
  <option value="option2"> option2 </option>
  <option value="option3"> option3 </option>
  <option value="option4"> option4 </option>
</select>
```

After I remove and append I want the options like:

```html
<select id="selectBox" name="selectBox">
  <option value="myoption"> myoption </option>
  <option value="option2"> option2 </option>
  <option value="option3"> option3 </option>
  <option value="option4"> option4 </option>
</select>
```

My Script is:

```js
$("#selectBox option[value='option1']").remove();
$("#selectBox").append('<option value="myoption">myoption </option> ');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectBox" name="selectBox">
  <option value="option"> option1 </option>
  <option value="option2"> option2 </option>
  <option value="option3"> option3 </option>
  <option value="option4"> option4 </option>
</select>
```

In my case, it can remove the option but append it at the last position.
Is there any way to work with index?

Comment: jquery has `.replace`.

Comment: .replaceWith works for me, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.replaceWith() works for me. Thanks

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29951509)

Comment: @Paul Already marked accepted that helped me

Answer (score 1):

You can take reference from below code, here I am removing and adding option dynamically at the bottom, but you can add anywhere using option index `select.options[select.options.length] = new Option('New Element', '0');`, just replace `select.options.length` with index:

```js
function addOption(){
 var select = document.getElementById("dynamic-select");
 select.options[select.options.length] = new Option('New Option', '0');
}

function removeOption(){
 var select = document.getElementById("dynamic-select");
 select.options[select.options.length - 1] = null;
}

function removeAllOptions(){
 var select = document.getElementById("dynamic-select");
 select.options.length = 0;
}
```

```html
<select id="dynamic-select">
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="2">two</option>
  <option value="3">three</option>
</select>

<button onclick="addOption()">add item</button>
<button onclick="removeOption()">remove item</button>
<button onclick="removeAllOptions()">remove all</button>
```